# Firebase: npm install -g firebase-tools failed

Tags: firebase

I've checked the Node and the npm.

```
Node: v14.15.1
npm: 7.18.1
```

Seems good to install according to the [Firebase CLI reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

But the bash gives information regarding several packages deprecated, corrupted, not supported, or files not being found. Is there any workaround? Or any issue on my side? Thank you for your time and patience.

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN tarball tarball data for rxjs@https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.6.7.tgz (sha512-
hTdwr+7yYNIT5n4AMYp85KA6yw2Va0FLa3Rguvbpa4W3I5xynaBZo41cM3XM+4Q6fRMj3sBYIR1VAmZMXYJvRQ==) seems
to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for ajv@https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv/-/ajv-6.12.6.tgz (sha512-j3
fVLgvTo527anyYyJOGTYJbG+vnnQYvE0m5mmkc1TK+nxAppkCLMIL0aZ4dblVCNoGShhm+kzE4ZUykBoMg4g==) seems to
 be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use
Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/bl
og/math-random for details.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for rxjs@https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.6.7.tgz (sha512-
hTdwr+7yYNIT5n4AMYp85KA6yw2Va0FLa3Rguvbpa4W3I5xynaBZo41cM3XM+4Q6fRMj3sBYIR1VAmZMXYJvRQ==) seems
to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for ajv@https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv/-/ajv-6.12.6.tgz (sha512-j3
fVLgvTo527anyYyJOGTYJbG+vnnQYvE0m5mmkc1TK+nxAppkCLMIL0aZ4dblVCNoGShhm+kzE4ZUykBoMg4g==) seems to
 be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/
request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\alex0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\85\37\70afeef260
d213e67e00318a7ce4a03acb0d956b414b6b7460baf6e96b85b7239c729da059a38d5c3375ccfb843a7d1323dec05821
1d5502664c5d826f45
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\alex0\AppData\Local\npm-cache
\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\85\37\70afeef260d213e67e00318a7ce4a03acb0d956b414b6b7460baf6e96b85b7
239c729da059a38d5c3375ccfb843a7d1323dec058211d5502664c5d826f45'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting the `node_modules` folder helped.